# How do I increase the marker size and center the text of my list items?

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple unordered list:

```html
<body>
    <div class="todo-section">
        <label for="bulletPoints">Todo:</label>
        <ul id="bulletPoints">
            <li>Apples</li>
            <li>Bananas</li>
            <li>Pears</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am using circles as markers and I have realized these are too small. I could increase the font size of the marker, but in this case, the text of my list-items is not aligned with my bullet points any more.

I have tried out different stylings to the extent that I cannot believe how difficult it is to simply increase only the marker size and still have a nicely designed list. Here are my latest css settings:

```css
.todo-section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.todo-section label {
  margin-top: .57rem;
}

#bulletPoints {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: circle;
  list-style-position: inside;
}


#bulletPoints li {
    line-height: 2rem;
}

#bulletPoints li::marker {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is that use from **sup** tag:

```css
.todo-section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.todo-section label {
  margin-top: .57rem;
}

#bulletPoints {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: circle;
  list-style-position: inside;
}


#bulletPoints li {
    line-height: 2rem;
    
}

#bulletPoints li::marker {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="todo-section">
        <label for="bulletPoints">Todo:</label>
        <ul id="bulletPoints">
            <li><sup>Apples</sup></li>
            <li><sup>Bananas</sup></li>
            <li><sup>Pears</sup></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `::marker` CSS pseudo-element:

```
ul li::marker {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2.5em;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

for center your text list
use for li
display: flex
align-items: center
justify-content: center
and for first problem use
Use ::marker CSS pseudo-element:
then use font-size

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own markers

```
        #bulletPoints {
          margin: 0;
          list-style-type: none;
          list-style-position: inside;
        }


        #bulletPoints li {
            line-height: 2rem;
        }
        
        #bulletPoints li:before {
            content: 'Օ';
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        
        /*
        #bulletPoints li::marker {
            padding-top: 10px;
            font-size: 2rem;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        */
```

Or just leave content:''; and load any image as an icon

Comment: This is not correct. `marker` pseudo-elements do not accept padding or margin style rules. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker